# Error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" after json fetching

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

After fetching a json file from server keep getting following mistake

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I understand that have problems with *locationsData*, which I'm fetching, but I assumed that it already has an array format due to the format of the parsed data (example, please, see below).

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "react-google-maps";

let locationsData;
fetch("http:///locations")
  .then(function (u) {
    return u.json();
  })
  .then(function (json) {
    locationsData = json;
  });

function Map() {
  const [selectedLoc, setSelectedLoc] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={14}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 49.55848, lng: 23.312481 }}
      >
        {locationsData.map((loc) => (
          <Marker
            key={loc._id}
            position={{
              lat: loc.gps[0],
              lng: loc.gps[1],
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(loc);
            }}
          />
        ))}

        {selectedLoc && (
          <InfoWindow
            position={{
              lat: selectedLoc.gps[0],
              lng: selectedLoc.gps[1],
            }}
            onCloseClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>{selectedLoc.name}</h2>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <WrappedMap
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=000`}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Server data example:

```
[
  {
    "gps": [11, 11],
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Name1"
  },
  {
    "gps": [22, 22],
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Name2"
  }
]
```

Comment: it is actually ***before*** json fetching, and there is your problem.

Comment: Try like, ```locationsData && locationsData.map((loc) => ( ... )```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `useEffect` and do the fetching in there. You will also have to store the data in the state so that the component will re-render once the data are fetched.

```js
function Map() {
  const [selectedLoc, setSelectedLoc] = useState(null);
  const [locationsData, setLocationsData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http:///locations")
      .then(function(u) {
        return u.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        setLocationsData(json);
      });
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={14}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 49.55848, lng: 23.312481 }}
      >
        {locationsData.map((loc) => (
          <Marker
            key={loc._id}
            position={{
              lat: loc.gps[0],
              lng: loc.gps[1],
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(loc);
            }}
          />
        ))}

        {selectedLoc && (
          <InfoWindow
            position={{
              lat: selectedLoc.gps[0],
              lng: selectedLoc.gps[1],
            }}
            onCloseClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>{selectedLoc.name}</h2>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thx! I changed useFetch to useEffect and it managed to compile, but the problem is that there are no point from the json file mapped on the map. (Disclaimer: I checked the correctness of the server gps)

Answer (score 1):

before it gets assigned (`locationsData = json;`), the `locationsData` is `undefined` as you stated here in the initial declaration: `let locationsData;`

so `undefined.map()` will throw you the error, you can do this to remain a consistent behavior:

```
let locationsData = [];
```

or you can have a validation before calling the `.map()` function:

```
  {Array.isArray(locationsData) && locationsData.map((loc) => (
      <Marker
        key={loc._id}
        position={{
          lat: loc.gps[0],
          lng: loc.gps[1],
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          setSelectedLoc(loc);
        }}
      />
  ))}
```

---

As @Gabriele pointed out, the fetch operation is placed outside of the component. You can do this to ensure the results get assigned correctly and the component will render it:

```
function Map() {
  const [selectedLoc, setSelectedLoc] = useState(null);
  const [locationsData, setLocationsData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http:///locations")
      .then(u => u.json())
      .then(json => setLocationsData(json));
  }, []); // Empty dependency, acts similar to componentDidMount

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={14}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 49.55848, lng: 23.312481 }}
      >
        {locationsData.map((loc) => (
          <Marker
            key={loc._id}
            position={{
              lat: loc.gps[0],
              lng: loc.gps[1],
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(loc);
            }}
          />
        ))}

        {selectedLoc && (
          <InfoWindow
            position={{
              lat: selectedLoc.gps[0],
              lng: selectedLoc.gps[1],
            }}
            onCloseClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>{selectedLoc.name}</h2>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: the fetch is happening outside the component and the result is stored in a normal variable. So the component will not re-render.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli you're right, it's not within the component. Let me update the answer a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @JeeMok! Tried all versions and the all compiled. However I still do not see the points on the map. May be there is sth wrong with me reading the values?
Because I do not see any points even with just validation, which should, as I understand, return at least static version of map.

Comment: @MemberUnit well the validation is only to avoid crashing when it didn't return what we expected as it should. Of course, if you wanted, you can skip the validation, but only if you can ensure it will always be an array.

Comment: Can you give any advice on how to tackle the problem, that currently there are no points on the Google Map? So the there are no Errors and the programm should read server values correctly, but it does not. 
Just to check the correctnes of the data, I launched the program on the local server, so it seems that there are no problems on that side.

Comment: The code seems alright, what version are you running on `react-google-maps`? and maybe if you can create another question with minimal reproducible example and that will be easier for everyone to look at the code and help

Comment: Sure, created  another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387186/mapping-positions-using-react-google-maps . As for the version of react-google-maps it's following: "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5" .

Answer (score 0):

Initialize locationData with empty array..

```
let locationsData= [];
```