# Mapping positions using react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a code, which should map locations from the server on the google map. It compiles, however there are no positions marked on google map.

It seems to me that the code is ok (thx to @JeeMok and @GabrielePetrioli), and I also checked correctens of the server data (gps coordinates, etc). So may be there are some problems with format, but Im not sure.

There version of reac google maps is : "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "react-google-maps";

function Map() {
  const [selectedLoc, setSelectedLoc] = useState(null);
  const [locationsData, setLocationsData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://0000/locations")
      .then((u) => u.json())
      .then((json) => setLocationsData(json));
  }, []); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={14}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 50.00, lng: 30.00 }}
      >
        {locationsData.map((loc) => (
          <Marker
            key={loc._id}
            position={{
              lat: loc.gps[0],
              lng: loc.gps[1],
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(loc);
            }}
          />
        ))}

        {selectedLoc && (
          <InfoWindow
            position={{
              lat: selectedLoc.gps[0],
              lng: selectedLoc.gps[1],
            }}
            onCloseClick={() => {
              setSelectedLoc(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>{selectedLoc.name}</h2>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <WrappedMap
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=000`}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example of the server data:

```
[
   {
      "gps": [
         50.010000,
         30.020000
      ],
      "temperature": [
         12,
         18
      ],
      "_id": "1",
      "address": "Address1",
      "name": "Name1",
      "description": "Desc1"
   },
   {
      "gps": [
         50.9347212,
         30.3506727
      ],
      "temperature": [
         12,
         18
      ],
      "_id": "2",
      "address": "Address2",
      "name": "Name2",
      "description": "Description2"
   }
]
```